# what is the relationship between MSS and congestion window

Tags: tcp

A TCP connection is using an MSS=500 bytes. Which of the following could be a realistic/valid value for the congestion window during its operation?

Can anyone tell me how to compute the result?

Comment: Where is the "following"?

Answer (score 0):

So like a realistic/valid value of the congestion window should be a integer multiple times of the maximum segment size(MSS).

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptkKv.jpg)

According to this image, the congestion window size increase exponentially, which means * 2 every time. For example, if your MSS is 500 bytes, possible congestion window size should be 500, 1000, 2000, 4000 and something like these.

Hope it's helpful. Cheers!